# Django: looping through multiple dictionaries in a template - or finding a better way

Tags: django

I have a school enrollment app and am trying to create a web-based report that lists each class for a semester, the teacher, assistants, and students.

You can see below that I am creating a dictionary with the key set as the class name and the value set to a list of students. However, I need to do the same thing for the assistants.

I can create something similar for the assistants of each class (there could be zero to unlimited assistants per class) but I'm not sure what to do after that and am thinking that this is not the best way to pass the data to the template.

If I have a student_dict and an assistant_dict passed to the template, how do I loop through them? I can't seem to find a way to filter on a dictionary key so it's not like I can loop through the assistant list and then create an inner loop that matches the assistant_dict[course] with the student_dict[course].   Or, maybe I can and am not able to figure it out.

Or, maybe there is a much simpler way to go about this.

Thank you for any advice you can offer.

```
schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(semester__name='2014 Fall').prefetch_related()
schedule_list = schedule.values_list('course_catalog__course_name', flat=True).order_by('semester_period__name')
student_dict=dict([(schedule_list,[]) for schedule_list in list(schedule_list)])

student_enrolls = StudentEnroll.objects.filter(schedule__semester__name = '2014 Fall').values_list('student__family_member__first_name', 'student__family_member__last_name', 'schedule__course_catalog__course_name')

for (fname, lname, course) in student_enrolls:
    student_dict[course].append(fname + ' ' + lname)
for k in student_dict.keys():
    student_dict[k].sort()
```

Comment: Can you show your models for each and the related foreign key fields?

Comment: Why do you need these dicts at all? Why not loop through the classes, and for each class output the students and the assistants via the existing relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would change the concept over to a course dictionary. Then for the value of each item it would have another dictionary, one key being the list of students and the other key being the list of assistants.

So your course dictionary would look like this:

```
{
    "course_id_1": {
        "students": [],
        "assistants": [],
    },
    "course_id_2": {
        "students": [],
        "assistants": [],
    }
}
```

Assuming you add the assistants the same way you do students, you could do as follows:

```
for (fname, lname, course) in student_enrolls:
    courses[course]['students'].append(fname + ' ' + lname)
for (fname, lname, course) in assistants:
    courses[course]['assistants'].append(fname + ' ' + lname)
for k in courses.keys():
    courses[k]['students'].sort()
    courses[k]['assistants'].sort()
```

That being said you could probably improve the performance of your solution by ordering your enrollment objects and then removing the `.sort()` calls

Comment: That seems simple enough. Thanks!